# How do I to stop submitting in first dropdown list in .jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a file called add.jsp that I add data to the database with Java.

In this file, I bring the leagues from the database with the first dropdownlist, and the teams of that league are displayed in the 2nd and 3rd Dropdown lists of the selected league.

The form starts as follows.

Since onchange="this.form.submit();" is in the first dropdown list section, when the selection is made, the form submits and goes to the addemp servlet.

How do I prevent the form from submitting when I select the Leagues from the first dropdown list? and how do I make it go to the addemp servlet only when I click on the bottom submit button after selecting all the data and logging in?

My code is as below between body tags..

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L02Gf.png)

[Without onchange event screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv5Tg.png)

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">


        <form class="form-group" action="addemp" method="post">


            <label class="form-label" for="name">Choose a League </label> <select
                name="leagues" id="leagues" class="form-control mb-3"
                style="width: 200px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="0">Select League</option>
                <%
        Connection conn;
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
            String query = "select * from leagues";
            stm = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
                <option value="<%=rs.getInt("league_id")%>"
                    <%
            if(request.getParameter("leagues")!= null) 
            {
                if(rs.getInt("league_id")==Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("leagues"))) 
                {
                    out.print("selected");
                }
            }
            %>><%=rs.getString("league_name")%></option>
                <%
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            %>
            </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Home Team</label> <select
                name="home_team" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">
                <option value="0">Select Home Team</option>
                <%
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
            String query = "select * from teams where league_id=?";
            PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            psmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("leagues"));
            ResultSet rset = psmt.executeQuery();
            while(rset.next()) 
            {
            %>
                <option value="<%=rset.getInt("team_id")%>">
                    <%=rset.getString("team_name")%></option>
                <%
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            %>
            </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Away Team</label> <select
                name="home_team" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">
                <option value="0">Select Away Team</option>
                <%
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
            String query = "select * from teams where league_id=?";
            PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            psmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("leagues"));
            ResultSet rset = psmt.executeQuery();
            while(rset.next()) 
            {
            %>
                <option value="<%=rset.getInt("team_id")%>">
                    <%=rset.getString("team_name")%></option>
                <%
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            %>
            </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Enter Match Date
                (YYYY-MM-DD)</label> <input name="match_date" type="text"
                class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px"> <label
                class="form-label" for="name">Home Score</label> <input
                name="home_score" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
                style="width: 200px;"> <label class="form-label"
                for="name">Away Score</label> <input name="away_score" type="text"
                class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;"> <label
                class="form-label" for="name">Home Team HT Score</label> <input
                name="home_ht_score" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
                style="width: 200px;"> <label class="form-label"
                for="name">Away Team HT Score</label> <input name="away_ht_score"
                type="text" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">

            <label class="form-label" for="name">Week</label> <input
                name="week" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
                style="width: 200px;">

            <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-4" type="submit">Save
                    Match Result</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to know why do you add onChange on select? do you want to do anything on onchange event? If I consider current given information then just remove onChange from select. Submit button is already good to go. its type is submit it should work.

If it does not work, let me know more details, I will try to solve your issue.

**Updated from here:**

you need to create a javascript function and call it onChange of first select. this function will reload this current page selected value of selection in current url.

```
funtion onLeagueChange(){
  var leagueValue = document.getElementById("leagues").value;
  window.location.href = your_url + "?leagues="+leagueValue;
}
```

this is solve your problem without using and other file.

**Your Updated Code**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-sm-4">


    <form class="form-group" action="addemp" method="post">


        <label class="form-label" for="name">Choose a League </label> <select
            name="leagues" id="leagues" class="form-control mb-3"
            style="width: 200px;" onchange="onLeagueChange()">
            <option value="0">Select League</option>
            <%
    Connection conn;
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
        String query = "select * from leagues";
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
    %>
            <option value="<%=rs.getInt("league_id")%>"
                <%
        if(request.getParameter("leagues")!= null) 
        {
            if(rs.getInt("league_id")==Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("leagues"))) 
            {
                out.print("selected");
            }
        }
        %>><%=rs.getString("league_name")%></option>
            <%
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        %>
        </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Home Team</label> <select
            name="home_team" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">
            <option value="0">Select Home Team</option>
            <%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
        String query = "select * from teams where league_id=?";
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        psmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("leagues"));
        ResultSet rset = psmt.executeQuery();
        while(rset.next()) 
        {
        %>
            <option value="<%=rset.getInt("team_id")%>">
                <%=rset.getString("team_name")%></option>
            <%
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        %>
        </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Away Team</label> <select
            name="home_team" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">
            <option value="0">Select Away Team</option>
            <%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams", "root", "Fener2013");
        String query = "select * from teams where league_id=?";
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        psmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("leagues"));
        ResultSet rset = psmt.executeQuery();
        while(rset.next()) 
        {
        %>
            <option value="<%=rset.getInt("team_id")%>">
                <%=rset.getString("team_name")%></option>
            <%
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        %>
        </select> <label class="form-label" for="name">Enter Match Date
            (YYYY-MM-DD)</label> <input name="match_date" type="text"
            class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px"> <label
            class="form-label" for="name">Home Score</label> <input
            name="home_score" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
            style="width: 200px;"> <label class="form-label"
            for="name">Away Score</label> <input name="away_score" type="text"
            class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;"> <label
            class="form-label" for="name">Home Team HT Score</label> <input
            name="home_ht_score" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
            style="width: 200px;"> <label class="form-label"
            for="name">Away Team HT Score</label> <input name="away_ht_score"
            type="text" class="form-control mb-3" style="width: 200px;">

        <label class="form-label" for="name">Week</label> <input
            name="week" type="text" class="form-control mb-3"
            style="width: 200px;">

        <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-4" type="submit">Save
                Match Result</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Without onchange, team names are not coming from database. 1st dropdownlist can select league names, after onchange event  2nd and 3rd dropdowlists are bring team names related league from database dynamically.

Comment: I added screenshot as "Without onchange event screenshot is here" above. Pls. check. Thanks.

Comment: you need to create a javascript function and call it onChange of first select.

this function will reload this current page selected value of selection in current url.

Comment: @EnBüyükFenerbahçe I have updated my answer kindly see my updated

Comment: Hi Awais, If it is possible can you modify in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @EnBüyükFenerbahçe please check my answer now

Comment: I just add javascript as : <script type="text/javascript"> 
function onLeagueChange(){
   var leagueValue = document.getElementById("leagues").value;
   window.location.href = localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/match/add2.jsp + "?leagues="+value;
 }
</script>    But I got this error in chrome console and teams drop down list not change still. (error is : add2.jsp:104 Uncaught ReferenceError: onLeagueChange is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (add.jsp:104:63)

Comment: javascript function is not defined correctly, it is not finding it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function onLeagueChange(){ var leagueValue = document.getElementById("leagues").value; window.location.href = "../add2.jsp?leagues="+value; } </script>

Comment: you need to add link in "link URL".

Comment: You can see  my full code is here : https://codeshare.io/eV8LbL

Comment: done check it please.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but after choosing league name , team names are not coming to 2nd ans 3rd dropdownlist still.

Comment: does page reload?

Comment: do you know how to debug javascript code? Does javascript function reloading page with appending selected leagues in url?

Comment: Page not reloaded. It's not shows URL in browser as you mentioned. Just show this URL : http://localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/match/add2.jsp and chrome console shows this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined
    onLeagueChange http://localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/match/add2.jsp:86
    onchange http://localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/match/add2.jsp:1

Comment: sorry my bad. in url replace value with leagueValue . I have updated code on codeshare kindly check now.

Comment: No problem. It's working wonderfully right now. Thanks for kindly supports and efforts. Regards..